# Freebsd equivalent build-essential

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I'm already familiar with Debian and Ubuntu. At the moment I'm fiddling around with FreeBSD on a server, after installing it I'm wondering what the best way would be to install the 'essential' compilation/make/gcc packages.

Comment: What are essential packages for you?

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83156/freebsd-base-packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FreeBSD always includes a compiler and basic build environment out of the box. There is no "build essential" type package, because it is not necessary.