# What advantages are there to running a server on Unix rather than Linux?

Tags: apache-httpd, performance, postfix

my question is fairly similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/why-would-someone-choose-freebsd-over-linux), but I'd like to be more specific. Quite a few years have passed since it was asked so it might be relevant to ask again..

I got hold of a pretty old piece of computer (core2duo CPU, 2 GB of RAM) and I though that now, finally, I can run a little home server with a few services: Postfix for email, Apache for a webserver, and Samba for local file sharing.

It has been years since I've used any form of Unix, so I'm curious, are there any actual advantages (performance, flexibility) to running those on Free/OpenBSD? What are the advantages of running the same applications on CentOS or Debian, except that it's just way more common? I would also guess that there are more drivers available for Linux distributions.

Comment: On my point of view it is due to garantee , solaris SUN  offered both included supports hardware and software & even networking.... just for example. It was the same thing for DEC & IBM. Concerning BSD vs Linux this is often more politic then really justified or sometimes it is just a licence preference.

Comment: Do you mean Gnu/Linux (as opposed to other Linux e.g. android)?

Comment: Gnu/Linux is a Unix. So are BSDs, and UNIX. Only UNIX is UNIX (not BSD, not Gnu/Linux). But dose the trademark matter? Yes Gnu/Linux lacks some standards tick points, but these are rarely used. It also has some added features. Gnu tools are usually better than the originals.

Comment: BSD Is POSIX compliant and has a strong following, especially amongst seasoned users. However, although the OpenBSD official documentation is excellent, there's generally a lot more info available online for Linux. (I can't speak for other Unices). If you're unsure and your main aim is to learn the basics well, I would use Linux (first) as the info and hardware support will be smoother.